# Jenkins: prevent triggering job that polls SCM in case the job commits by itself

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a funny situation in which:

1. A job polls for SVN changes and is built when such changes are identified
2. The job commits by itself to the same place
3. There are changes in the SVN so the job is built again, and again, and again.

Is there a way to prevent such scenario? Somehow to reset the SCM polling?

Comment: There really are no good reasons the build should check into source control.  The concerns should be separated.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the advanced section in the subversion configuration. I would use the excluded user option. However, that means Jenkins should use its own SVN user for the commits.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to install [SVN post-commit hooks](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) to notify Jenkins to build the job. You would set the hook to not poll Jenkins when the Jenkins SVN user committed. This would also mean turning off the jenkins job polling the SCM.

Comment: This is not always an option. You don't always have control over the SCM to implement post commit hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in the current versions (starting 2.0) is to have particular commit messages to be excluded from causing a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I'd share my solution since all the other solutions are pretty old.

If you're using the Subversion plugin, you can configure SVN to ignore commits that contains a particular revprop name.

Here's an excerpt of the help section:

> If set, and Jenkins is set to poll for changes, Jenkins will ignore any revisions that are marked with the given revision property (revprop) when determining if a build needs to be triggered. This can be used to exclude commits done by the build itself from triggering another build, assuming the build server commits the change with the correct revprop.

I'd like to note that the configuration that I'm referring to is the global SVN configuration (found on http://jenkins_address/configure), not the configuration of the particular build.

**EDIT:** Upon further investigation, I found that in the build configuration page, you can click on the *Advanced* button under *Pipeline*, you'll have a few chances of how you want to ignore a commit (by user, commit message, prop, etc)